# Android - Drain battery quickly on purpose

Tags: android, battery

I am nearly finished with my app and last functionality to be made is to call specific action when battery level reaches below specific level.

So for test purposes I am wondering - how can I drain battery?

P.S - Using AVD wont work since my app is using Google Play services so I am testing app on my phone.

Comment: Run an n64 emulator playing super mario 64 on highest brightness with wifi, data, and bluetooth all on

Comment: See (app-free!) solution in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/is-there-an-app-that-will-drain-my-battery/57100

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For fastest drain turn on at once all battery drainers:

- Acquire a Wake lock with Full screen brightness (No. 1 battery drainer)
- Vibration
- GPS with zero time polling intervals
- Turn on WiFi and continuously issue http requests
- Turn on Bluetooth and continuously issue scan commands

And, since you're a smart guy, you will probably use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batterydrainer&hl=en) instead of hand-coding all of the above.

Comment: I just ended up:
Instead of getting required minimal value for battery like:
if(current_level <= UserSetting)
I just took my current level of battery and made it less than two, turned brightness to max and music playing + awaked lockscreen + flashlight. Chosing correct answer for linked app, I tried searching for such but all I found was battery saved.

Comment: Checked some reviews of your suggested app: "Youtube drains better than you..." I think I'll use youtube with full brightness instead... Navigation is another option, it use to drain my phone in 3 hours. Still very slow, since I want to test a power bank, which can fully charge the phone at least 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

There is an AVD target that contains Play Services (Google APIs target). [image: avd]

Edit: you should also be able to use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) from what I've read. It's also much faster than the stock emulator, but if your app uses any native code it may not work.

Comment: Yeah I make app in Native.